# How to let the user chek only 2 check boxes from an unknown number of checkboxes PyQt5?

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt5

Let the checkboxes be random(5-10), I want to restrict the user to select any two of the checkboxes. `self.check_boxes = [QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.dockWidgetContents_2) for i in col_names]`
This is a list of checkboxes that I'm generating. Please help me make my desired checkboxes. Here's my code:

`def uncheck(self, state):`

```
`if state == Qt.CheckState.Checked:
    global checkedItems
    try:
        senderCheckBox = [i for i in self.check_boxes if i.isChecked() and not i in checkedItems][0]
        checkedItems[0] = checkedItems[1]
        checkedItems[1] = senderCheckBox
        itemsToUncheck = [i for i in self.check_boxes if not i in checkedItems]
        for checkBox in itemsToUncheck:
            checkBox.setChecked(False)`
```

Comment: Use a persistent list, connect the `toggled` signal, and append/remove the check boxes every time they are checked/unchecked, and programmatically uncheck the first items of the list until the list size is the desired count.

Comment: Note: if you already tried something, please show us what you've got so far, even if it doesn't work as expected. It's also important to know what should happen when the maximum number of check boxes is checked: should checking another checkbox be prevented? or should a previous checkbox be unchecked? and according to what order?

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your comment! I solved this problem as well as I could, but if you have any advice on how to make my code better, please do. I've put my code up there in the question : )

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the checked number, you must track the order in which checkboxes are toggled.

To get a reference to the toggled checkbox, you can then use [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html), which has a [`buttonToggled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonToggled) signal that emits both the checkbox and the new state.

In the function connected to that signal, you *append* the checkbox to a *persistent* list (do *not* use globals!) if the state is checked and uncheck the keep unchecking the first item(s) until the number is respected; in the same function, if the state is *unchecked* you then remove checkboxes from that list. In this way, since signals are synchronous in the same thread, you can use a simple `while` loop and will be certain that the order will always be respected.

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.checked = []
        self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(exclusive=False)
        for i in range(5):
            checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Check {}'.format(i + 1))
            layout.addWidget(checkBox)
            self.buttonGroup.addButton(checkBox)

        self.buttonGroup.buttonToggled.connect(self.limitChecked)

    def limitChecked(self, checkBox, state):
        if state:
            self.checked.append(checkBox)
            # do *NOT* use a "for", as the list might change in the meantime
            while len(self.checked) > 2:
                self.checked[0].setChecked(False)
        else:
            if checkBox in self.checked:
                self.checked.remove(checkBox)
```